# How to find the directional derivative by definition?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, scalar-fields

I have the following function:

$$
f(x,y)=3xy^2+e^{xy}
$$

I first calculated it in the normal way, using the unit vector, and the resulting value was $\sqrt2$.

Then, I tried calculating it by definition using
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac {f(2+t,0+t)-f(2,0)}{t}
$$

and the result was infinite.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The directional derivative at which point and with respect to which vector?

Comment: And how could we tell you what goes wrong if you do not show us your calculations?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A direction vector is needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, the point is (2,0) and the vector is (1,1). I calculated the directional derivative in an online calculator so I assumed it was right. Then, I also calculated the limit in an online calculator. Their value though is different, so maybe something else is wrong?
Just in case, the formula I used for the normal way was the gradient times the unit vector.

Comment: You haven’t included any information about how concluded that the limit was infinite. As such, we can’t tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result $\sqrt2$ is the directional derivative to the unit vector $v = (\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2}) $ .

So, by definition, it goes:
$$\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{f(2+\frac{h}{\sqrt2},\frac{h}{\sqrt2}) - f(2,0)}{h}}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{f(2+h,h) - f(2,0)}{{\sqrt2}h}}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{3(2+h)h^2 + e^{(2+h)h} - 1}{{\sqrt2}h}}$$
($\frac{0}{0}$type, use L'Hôpital's rule)
$$=\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{9h^2 + 12h + (2h+2)e^{(2+h)h}}{\sqrt2}}$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt2}$$
$$=\sqrt2$$

So, there's no problem.